# Plotly hover data and hover text

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

My input:

```
df=(pd.DataFrame({'label_color':['white','white','cyan','cyan','cyan','cyan','white','white'],
                  'label_quality':['white','white','red','green','green','red','white','white'],
'label':['foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','foo']}))
```

My code:

```
df['color_value'] = 1
df['quality_value'] = 1

fig = px.bar(df, y=['color_value','quality_value'],
             x=[1]*len(df),
             orientation='h',
             barmode='group',
             template='plotly_white', hover_data=[df.index.values,df.label])

fig.data[0]['marker']['color'] = df['label_color'].tolist()
fig.data[1]['marker']['color'] = df['label_quality'].tolist()
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color='rgb(8,48,107)')
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, yaxis_title='foo', xaxis_title='')
fig.show()
```

My output:
[image].

As you can see, I create some custom plot within bar chart. And now I try make some "glitter", but a little bit confused. What I **want&expect**: I try hide in popup (hover text) any `x=1`, `variable=quality_value` (i.e values from x and y axis) and just leave
only labels from `hover_data` within custom name not like now (`hover_data_0` and `label`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fig.update_traces(hovertemplate)` with the following setup:

```
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = 'hover_data_0=%{customdata[0]}<br>label=%{customdata[1]}<extra></extra>')
```

#### Plot 1:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df=(pd.DataFrame({'label_color':['white','white','cyan','cyan','cyan','cyan','white','white'],
                  'label_quality':['white','white','red','green','green','red','white','white'],
'label':['foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','foo']}))

df['color_value'] = 1
df['quality_value'] = 1

fig = px.bar(df, y=['color_value','quality_value'],
             x=[1]*len(df),
             orientation='h',
             barmode='group',
             template='plotly_white', hover_data=[df.index.values,df.label])

fig.data[0]['marker']['color'] = df['label_color'].tolist()
fig.data[1]['marker']['color'] = df['label_quality'].tolist()
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color='rgb(8,48,107)')
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, yaxis_title='foo', xaxis_title='')
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = 'hover_data_0=%{customdata[0]}<br>label=%{customdata[1]}<extra></extra>')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I rise error: "Full figure generation requires the kaleido package" Where I use Anaconda as python environment. Does not matter its still work without line f=fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)

Comment: @TeoK You don't need it either. It's jsut a way to inspect the struvture of plotly figures. Thank you for accepting my answer.